# Read XML file to a Spark dataframe

Tags: xml, apache-spark

I have an XML file in the below format.

```
<LEVEL1 A1="a1" A2="a2" A3="ss">
  <LEVEL2 A1="a1" A2="a2" A3="a3">
    <LEVEL3>
      <ITEM A1="a1" A2="a2" A3="a3"/>
      <ITEM A1="b1" A2="22" A3="b3"/>
      <ITEM A1="c1" A2="c2" A3="c3"/>
    </LEVEL3>
  </LEVEL2>
</LEVEL1>
```

I need to load this file into a Spark dataframe using PySpark and access the various nodes and attributes.

I have tried loading the XML file into a Spark dataframe using the below code. The code runs without errors, but seems like the dataframe is empty.

```
df1 = spark.read.format('xml').options(rowTag='LEVEL1').load('sample.xml')
df2 = spark.read.format('xml').options(rowTag='LEVEL2').load('sample.xml')
df3 = spark.read.format('xml').options(rowTag='LEVEL3').load('sample.xml')
df1.show()
df2.show()
df3.show()
```

Any help in loading this file to a dataframe is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Databricks' spark-xml library right [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "foo")
  .load("bar.xml")
```

Comment: Tried with this option too. The data frame will have value only for the first tag and rest of them is null.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `.option("rowTag", "<>")` and `.option("rootTag", "<>")` both